# CSS Nav Transparent Background

Tags: css, navigation, nav

I am trying to get this transparent background to work. When the nav drops down, I want the entire background of the list to be transparent and the hover to not be transparent.

UPDATE: [This is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imakeitpretty/Z8Cu8/)

Comment: Please post your HTML too. And a jsFiddle example would be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
ul#navigation li:hover > a
{
    background:#fff;
    color:#4dbaf2;
}
```

to:

```
#navigation li a:hover
{
    background:#fff;
    color:#4dbaf2;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Cu8/5/

### Updated:

Then you would also need to add this to your CSS file:

```
#navigation li ul li a
{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Cu8/6/

But I'm not really sure if this is what you asked for?

Comment: I need the non-hover state of the drop down to be white opacity .5 also. This way it is transparent until it's hovered over.